# How to create MultiLevel Dynamic dropdown using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create Multilevel Dropdown.

I have default dropdown with values

Ex. Parent Dropdown with Id='ddl1'

If we select value from it then load data from server with selected and Create new dropdown name as child dropdown, and again select value from child and load data from server, if data present then create child dropdown.

we have to create drowpdown, till n level.

'Ex. i am creating like below'

```
function createdropdown(id) {

 var labelHtml = "<tr id='trFormType" + id + "' class='trFormType'><td><label class='tdLabel'>" + labelFormType + " * </label></td>";
 labelHtml += "<td><select class='ddlFormType' id='ddlFormType" + id + "' name='ddlFormType" + id + "'  >";
    labelHtml  += "<option value=''";
    labelHtml += ">" + labelSelect + "</option>";
    labelHtml += "</select></td></tr>";

    return labelHtml;
}
```

var selectedId='';    $(".ddlFormType").live("click", function () {    selectedId= "#" + $(this).prop('id');    });

$(selectedId).live("change", function () {       $.ajax({    url: Url + 'Method/' +     (selectedId).val(),    type: 'GET',    dataType: 'json',    cache: false,             timeout: 9000,    success: function (data) {    $("#detailTable tbody").append(createdropdown(currentId));    }
});

'But .change event not get fired, for dyncamically created dropdown'

'Hope you can understand?'

Comment: look up cascading dropdown

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. Half your code is not formatted.

Answer (score 0):

For creating n level dropdowns you need to create a dropdown in ajax callback like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "Your URL",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
       $("Your Dropdown Conatiner").append("<select><option name="option1" value="1"></option>...</select>");
    },
    error: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanxs Hamed,

As you suggested ok.

But do you think will it help.

How can .change event will fire, to get Correct Id of selected value and then create dropdown.

I tried like : 
$("#ddlChild" + selectedId).live("change", function () {
$.ajax({.....});
});

But its not work

but

Answer (score 0):

It think your problem is that you are creating the select after the DOM has been fully loaded and jQuery has already registered all events.

If you want to add dinamically N selects you should include a call to register it inside the code you are adding to the DOM, check this sample:

```
  <div id="select-container"></div>

  <script>
    function CreateSelect(id){
        return `<select id="ddl` + id +  `">
                    <option value="Opcion">Opcion<\/option>
                    <option value="Opcion2">Opcion 2<\/option>
                <\/select>
                <script>
                    RegisterSelectChangeEvent(` + id + `);
                <\/script>`;
    }

    function RegisterSelectChangeEvent(id){
      console.log("Event Raised");
      $("#ddl" + id).on("change", function (e) {
          jQuery("#select-container").append(CreateSelect(id+1));
      });
    }

    (function(){
         jQuery("#select-container").append(CreateSelect(1));
    })();
  </script>
```

You can see it working here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQRqYY